# Visual Studio 2013 is not recognizing the SQLParameter object

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, reference, sqlclient

I am having an issue with  Visual Studio. I am unable to use SQLParameter in my code:

```
var returnParameter = new SQLParameter("@SqlStatement", SqlDbType.VarChar);
returnParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.Parameters.Add(returnParameter);
```

Visual Studio Info:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2013
Version 12.0.31101.00 Update 4
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.5.51641
```

Also here is a screen shot:

[image: Code Issue]

I am using the namespace:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

Can some please tell me why VS doesn't recognize the SQLParameter and what I can do to discover the reason why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Class names are case sensitive. You should have

```
var returnParameter = new SqlParameter("@SqlStatement", SqlDbType.VarChar);
```

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Maybe the color scheme is hiding the error that should be on the unknown type SQLParameter.

Comment: Wow.... Didn't even notice that. Thanks

Comment: @SteveWellens Idk that is the default color scheme

Comment: @nate That may be but if it is hiding errors, it's not a good scheme.

Comment: @SteveWellens I agree